# dlfileentry guest permission liferay cannot view images

Tags: image, view, permissions, liferay

I am using Liferay 6.1. I needed a persistance folder where registrated users could upload images by articles in my personal page. The guest user could access to all articles in data base.

I created a folder from "Documents and Multimedia" from portal's Liferay and I can store and load datas without problems in this folder, but the guest user cannot view images' article.

I try change permissions from portal's Liferay from folder's permission, and in all checks of guest user, only are enabled two, "view" and "access", the two checks are checked but the guest user cannot see it.

page referer: http://pachonweb.no-ip.org

You can try create a account and try create a article with images uploaded.
If uyou need more information about my system, say me it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: solve, the problem was in the portal's permissions. I added to guest user permissions to Document Library Visor and after click in the new link in the new row in the table and here check all checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve, the problem was in the portal's permissions. I added to guest user permissions to Document Library Visor and after click in the new link in the new row in the table and here check all checkbox.